# Losing last array element when adding newest one

Tags: java, arrays

I am having a problem of losing all elements, except the currently added element, in my array. I am getting the correct sums and lengths, but I can not longer reference old elements.

```
public class Lab7Model
{
    int ordersTotal;
    double[] priceArray;
    double prices_d, pricetotal_d, sum, priceavg_d;

public void statscompute()
{
    ordersTotal = ordersTotal + 1;
    c.statsframe.setTitle("Statistics for ("+ordersTotal+") orders.");
    prices_d = Double.parseDouble(c.pricedisplay);
    priceArray = new double[ordersTotal];

    priceArray[ordersTotal-1] = prices_d;

    for (int x = 0; x < priceArray.length; x++)
    {
        sum = sum + priceArray[x];
    }
    priceavg_d = sum/priceArray.length;
}
}
```

Comment: Consider making a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You are not adding anything you are 'setting' in some position a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
priceArray = new double[ordersTotal];
```

This creates an *entirely new array*, which of course has all elements set to 0.

You could copy the elements from the old array into the new array, with something like this:

```
double[] newArray = new double[ordersTotal];
for(int k = 0; k < ordersTotal - 1; k++)
    priceArray[k] = newArray[k];
priceArray = newArray;
```

or using System.arraycopy.

Or you could use a collection, which handles this for you, by making the following changes:

- Import java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList
- Change `double[] priceArray;` to `List<Double> priceList = new ArrayList<>();`
- Remove `priceArray = new double[ordersTotal];`
- Change `priceArray[ordersTotal-1] = prices_d;` to `priceList.add(prices_d);`
- Change `priceArray.length` to `priceList.size()`
- Change `priceArray[x]` to `priceList.get(x)`

Comment: I followed your steps-- thank you. The first execution produces the correct sum (say, 4.0) and average (4.0/1=4.0). The second execution (5.5 added) will produce an incorrect sum (13.5), thus, producing an incorrect average (6.75 as opposed to 4.75).

 public void statscompute()
 {
  ordersTotal = ordersTotal + 1;
  c.statsframe.setTitle("Statistics for ("+ordersTotal+") orders.");
  prices_d = Double.parseDouble(c.pricedisplay);
      
  priceAcc.add(prices_d);
  
  for (int x = 0; x < priceAcc.size(); x++)
  {
   sum = sum + priceAcc.get(x);
  }
  priceavg_d = sum/priceAcc.size();

Comment: Found it. I had to set 'sum = 0;' at the top of the method to reset it each time. It was adding the old (4.0) sum to the new (4.0+5.5) sum, making 13.5.

Answer (score 0):

You recreate the array each time you call `statscompute()` by line

```
priceArray = new double[ordersTotal];
```

You should use `List<Double>`, and do

```
priceArray.add(prices_d)
```

instead of

```
priceArray[ordersTotal-1] = prices_d;
```

or do some tricks with `System.arraycopy()` if you really have to use array instead of list (I guess, it is not your case and using `List<Double>` is best way)